# What community to use for asking about the Apache server?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What community should I use for asking a question about the Apache server?

This is the error.

```
5:38:10 PM [Apache] Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
5:38:10 PM [Apache] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
5:38:10 PM [Apache] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:38:10 PM [Apache] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:38:10 PM [Apache] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:38:10 PM [Apache] If you need more help, copy and post this
5:38:11 PM [Apache] entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: What apache server (http, couch, [others](http://www.apache.org/index.html#projects-list))? what is the problem you are having?

Comment: i will edit the question

Answer (score 7):

- You have a question about Windows and the services running on it.
- You do not appear to be a professional system administrator.

This would lead me to point more in the direction of [Super User](http://superuser.com) and its [Apache tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apache).

That said, you will need to include *significantly* more information and probably do a bit of trouble shooting on your own. This would include:

- What are the configuration files this is using?
- When the server isn't up, can you connect to that port?
- What other services and applications are running?

And of course, make sure you search first.